# nginx basic auth not worked whith txt

Tags: nginx, web-config

Why basic auth in nginx not worket with *.txt files?

Nginx config:

```
location ^/(gp|icq|irc)/* {
    auth_basic "Closed";
    auth_basic_user_file /home/user/etc/htpasswd;
    location ~* .php$ {
        try_files     $uri = 404;
        include       fastcgi_params_std;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/user.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}
```

Example:

http://old.prankru.net/gp/test.txt - not work

http://old.prankru.net/gp/ - work

Comment: Config looks correct. Maybe are you using alias, other location "capturing" txt files or other rules having impact? BTW: it is good idea (for security reasons) to set "server_tokens off". Now i see that you use old version of nginx.

Comment: Nope. Standart config.
Ups... forgot. Thanks